# Dracaena: does it need a repot?

Tags: repotting, dracaena

Please consider this plant:
[image]
It is in the same soil/pot from about 10 years, without any care that some water.

After starting to try take some care, ( ie adding some fertilizer), the plant developed a new born tree in the middle. What is best to do, completely repot by replacing all the soil, just put in another bigger pot and add some soil? What to do with the newborn? could be all repotted together or is it better to have that small plant in another separate pot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plant does not need repotting. If you do so it will just sit until it is somewhat pot bound again. Sometimes called D. Marginata it has now been reclassed as [Dracaena reflexa var angustifolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracaena_reflexa#Dracaena_reflexa_var._angustifolia).

The most common problems with this plant are:

- not enough light
- too much water
- spider mites

The light levels in the picture are too low.  I suggest moving it closer to the window or opening the drapes during the day.

Spider mites look like grains of salt and can be seen at the base of the leaf axils.  They can be controlled with 5 ml of dish soap to 1 liter of water mixed together.  Take a cloth, dip in the solution, and cover all the leaves top and bottom.

Low light or spider mites can cause the leaves to drop which can be seen in the photo.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did repot before your answer. Now I have two of them :) They survived my treatment till now, I think that having a new soil and a better draining one is not so bad after 10 years being in the same, what do you think?

Comment: @FelicePollano good drainage is always better, more light is always good